# Изменение цвета JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing

Нужно изменить цвет полоски прогресса. Метод `setBackground` не помогает.

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.ORANGE);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.BLUE);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.RED);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.GREEN);
```

Это тоже не оказывает никакого эффекта.
Как можно изменить цвет полосы прогресса?
Предполагаю, что нужно изменить метод, в котором происходит отрисовка, но найти этот метод не могу.

Comment: Это должно работать. Покажите, пожалуйста, как вы пытались.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод `setBackground` изменяет цвет фона. Для того чтобы изменить цвет самой полосы прогресса нужно использовать метод `setForeground`. Например:

```
jProgressBar1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: Это то что нужно, пока искал в инете видел что писали и такой способ, но думал что это изменяет только цвет текста.

Answer (score 5):

Вариант с `UIManager`, [описанный в англоязычном Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10774080/980828), отлично работает. Скорее всего вы что-то не так делаете.

Вот пример:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private int counter = 0;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public Main() {
        super("JProgressBar");
        setSize(300, 50);

        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.ORANGE);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.BLUE);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.RED);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.GREEN);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();

        getContentPane().add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        addWindowListener(wndCloser);
        setVisible(true);
        while (counter <= 100) {
            Runnable runme = () -> progressBar.setValue(counter);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runme);
            counter++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модифицировал пример `JProgressBar` [по ссылке](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Progressbardemosetselectionbackgroundselectionforegroundandforeground.htm).

Comment: Я верю что он работает, но он не работает на windows))

Comment: @Bleser, вы попробовали этот код на Windows и не получилось?

Comment: Когда попробовал этот метод ничего не изменилось, пришлось гугулить дальш и задавать вопрос здесь.